# Rails 3.1: Querying Postgres for records within a time range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, datetime, timezone

In my app I have a `Person` model. Each `Person` has an attribute `time_zone` that specifies their default time zone. I also have an `Event` model. Each `Event` has a `start_time` and `end_time` timestamp, saved in a Postgres database in UTC time.

I need to create a query that finds events for a particular person that fall between midnight of one day and midnight of the next. The `@todays_events` controller variable hold the results of the query.

Part of the reason that I'm taking this approach is that I may have people from other time zones looking at the list of events for a person. I want them to see the day as the person would see the day and not based on the time zone they are in as an observer.

For whatever reason, I'm still getting some events from the previous day in my result set for `@todays_events.` My guess is that I'm comparing a UTC timestamp with a non-UTC parameter, or something along those lines. Generally, only events that begin or end in the evening of the previous day show up on the query result list for today.

Right now, I'm setting up:

```
@today    = Time.now.in_time_zone(@person.time_zone).midnight.to_date
@tomorrow = (@today + 1.day ).to_datetime
@today    = @today.to_datetime
```

My query looks like:

```
@todays_activities = @person.marks.where("(start_time >= ? AND start_time < ?) OR (end_time >= ? AND end_time < ?);", @today, @tomorrow, @today, @tomorrow ).order("start_time DESC")
```

How should I change this so that I'm guaranteed only to receive results from today (per the `@person.time_zone` in the `@todays_activities` query?

Comment: Note: I'm storing the whole time zone string in the `@person.time_zone` field, not just the offset.

Comment: One of the offending events has the following in the db table for `start_time`: `2011-12-10 23:28:00` and `end_time`: `2011-12-11 03:00:00` with `time_zone` of `Eastern Time (US & Canada)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're losing track of your timezones when you call `to_date` so don't do that:

```
@today    = Time.now.in_time_zone(@person.time_zone).midnight.utc
@tomorrow = @today + 1.day
```

When you `some_date.to_datetime`, you get a DateTime instance that is in UTC so the result of something like this:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone(@person.time_zone).midnight.to_date.to_datetime
```

will have a time-of-day of 00:00:00 and a time zone of UTC; the 00:00:00 is the correct time-of-day in `@person.time_zone` but not right for UTC (unless, of course, `@person` is in  in the +0 time zone).

And you could simplify your query with [`overlaps`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html):

```
where(
    '(start_time, end_time) overlaps (timestamp :today, timestamp :tomorrow)',
    :today => @today, :tomorrow => @tomorrow
)
```

Note that [`overlaps` works with half-open intervals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html):

> Each time period is considered to represent the half-open interval `start <= time < end`, unless start and end are equal in which case it represents that single time instant.

Comment: Awesome! This is the single best explanation of this that I have seen after a lot of searching. I didn't know about overlaps, either  Thank you very much! Time zones are frustrating!

Comment: With `overlaps` in this context, using your code as shown, I think that `@today` and `@tomorrow` need to be cast. This error is thrown: `PGError: ERROR:  function pg_catalog.overlaps(timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, unknown, unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: ...arks"."person_id" = 1 AND ((start_time, end_time) overlaps (...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: @Clay: Try adding some casts: `overlaps (:today::timestamp, :tomorrow:timestamp)` or `overlaps (timestamp :today, timestamp :tomorrow)`. And for the record, I hate timezones too, almost as much as I hate DST.