# Comparing dates on heroku pgsql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to do a selection for Outprojects with start date within this week;

```
Outproject.where('start_at > ? and start_at < ?', Time.now.at_beginning_of_week.to_time,(Time.now.at_beginning_of_week + 5.days).to_time)
```

This works without problem locally (running postgresql), but on heroku it gives a empty result (even though it should not).

I have tried with .to_time (as above), with .to_date and without anything and DateTime instead of Time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8468036/724036) will help

Comment: You need to add timezone on heroku config. http://blog.pardner.com/2012/08/setting-the-default-time-zone-for-a-heroku-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Outproject.where('start_at >= ? and start_at <= ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_week.utc,(DateTime.now.beginning_of_week + 5.days).utc)
```

The [default time zone for postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) is UTC.